# "SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized" when trying to use conda

Tags: python, syntax-error, conda

I'm facing this problem whenever I'm trying to access any anaconda command. In fact, when I try to open my virtual environment it's showing there too

I have re-installed my anaconda navigator but still no result

```
C:\Users\Gagan Singh>activate tensorflow1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\gagan singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 30, in <module>
    from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cytoolz'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\gagan singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\gagan singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Gagan Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\conda.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\gagan singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .main import main  # NOQA
  File "c:\users\gagan singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 46, in <module>
    from ..base.context import context
  File "c:\users\gagan singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, MapParameter, PrimitiveParameter,
  File "c:\users\gagan singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .._vendor.toolz.functoolz import excepts
  File "c:\users\gagan singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\toolz\functoolz.py", line 467
    f.__name__ for f in reversed((self.first,) + self.funcs),
    ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

Comment: Seems your `toolz` is old and `cytoolz` is not present. Try `conda update toolz` and `conda install cytoolz`. That said... regarding your "need a solution asap!!!" - please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: The trouble is, these conda statements produce the same error!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `pip3 uninstall conda` solved the problem.

The reason was  miniconda trying to use pip's executables. It happened when I installed `conda` using `pip3` first and then using miniconda.