# Installing Miniconda in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, conda, miniconda

I am trying to install Miniconda in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. When trying to run the script Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh, it's not being successful.

I am getting this error when trying to run `conda init` after installing. The installation is not being successful. When I run `conda list`, it shows me that Miniconda is not installed. Can anyone help?

```
./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh: 494: [[: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 42, in <module>
    from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cytoolz/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .functoolz import *
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 9, in init cytoolz.functoolz
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cytoolz/_signatures.py", line 1, in <module>
    from toolz._signatures import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toolz'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 626, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 85, in _main
    from ..base.context import context
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, LoadError, MapParameter, PrimitiveParameter,
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .._vendor.toolz.functoolz import excepts
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/_vendor/toolz/functoolz.py", line 467
    f.__name__ for f in reversed((self.first,) + self.funcs),
    ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 42, in <module>
    from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cytoolz/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .functoolz import *
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 9, in init cytoolz.functoolz
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cytoolz/_signatures.py", line 1, in <module>
    from toolz._signatures import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toolz'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dreamepic/Desktop/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 162, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args)
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 630, in conda_exception_handler
    return handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 620, in handle_exception
    print_unexpected_error_message(e)
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 561, in print_unexpected_error_message
    from conda.base.context import context
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, LoadError, MapParameter, PrimitiveParameter,
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .._vendor.toolz.functoolz import excepts
  File "/home/dreamepic/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/_vendor/toolz/functoolz.py", line 467
    f.__name__ for f in reversed((self.first,) + self.funcs),
    ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
If you'd prefer that conda's base environment not be activated on startup, 
   set the auto_activate_base parameter to false: 

conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Comment: That's more a question of administration and/or a bug report, but not a programming question suitable for this forum. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

This helped me `pip3 uninstall conda`. This is from another stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159093/syntaxerror-generator-expression-must-be-parenthesized-when-trying-to-use-con)